# Insert large XML into Sql Server -2008

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying insert a large xml document (about 10MB) into a Sql Server 2008 table, the XML document is built at run-time.

Is there a better way to perform this insert. I'm using a simple insert command with one parameter of type string, but it doesn't work. In the table, the field is showing a NULL value.

Is there a way to do this with a single insert?

Comment: Is it really an issue with the size? Does your way of inserting the XML work if the document is smaller?

Comment: What SQL Server datatype are you using for the field?

Comment: The problem is encoding.
In my XML the encoding is UTF-8 and SQL Server 2008 uses UTF-16 by default.
I needed change this.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: @George, you should write your comment as an answer and accept it, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `BULK INSERT` expression to increase performance.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188365.aspx